# cloudformation update-stack with --cli-input-json and TemplateBody

Tags: aws-cloudformation, aws-cli

I am trying to use `aws cloudformation update-stack` with `--cli-input-json` but I also want the `"TemplateBody":"[...]"` value to point to a file like I can do with `--template-body file://template.yml`.

Is that possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No it's not supported.

You'll get this error message:

> An error occurred (ValidationError) when calling the UpdateStack operation: Template format error: unsupported structure.

Firstly, your template body has to be JSON in the `cli-input-json` so let's say you have `template.json`.

When you provide `--template-body` via the command line, the CLI realises that you're providing a file to be read, reads it and then supplies the JSON  contents to the API.

However, when you use [`cli-input-json`](https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/cloudformation/update-stack.html#options), the CLI parses it literally<sup>1</sup> & identifies `file://template.json` as invalid JSON that isn't in the [CloudFormation template format](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/template-anatomy.html).

---

<sup>1</sup> *You can see this if you run your command using `--debug` (this is `CreateStack` but same concept applies):*

> 2023-09-30 11:29:17,259 - MainThread - botocore.endpoint - DEBUG - Making request for OperationModel(name=CreateStack) with params: {'url_path': '/', 'query_string': '', 'method': 'POST', 'headers': {'Content-Type': 'xxx', 'User-Agent': 'xxx'}, 'body': {'Action': 'CreateStack', 'Version': '2010-05-15', 'StackName': 'xxx', **'TemplateBody': 'file://template.json'**}, 'url': 'xxx', 'context': {'client_region': 'xxx', 'client_config': <botocore.config.Config object at 0x10fa0a650>, 'has_streaming_input': False, 'auth_type': None}}